# Merge multiple tr with same value/ID in jquery

Tags: jquery, html-table, toggle

Its been so long since I researched and found nothing. This was the problem I'm facing, I have a table, populated from database. All I want to do is to merge all the table rows `<tr>` with same value(patient ID) into one tr.

For example I have four patients and one of them have gone through two studies:

```
 Patiend ID       Patient Name     Study
    1111            Angela          XRAY
    2222            Bena            Ultrasound
    3333            Luis            CT Scan
    1111            Angela          Ultrasound
```

Aside from merging the same patient, the client also want to add "+" sign so that the client will know that that patient gone through 2 or more studies. And if the client click on the "+" sign, the merge table row will expand showing all the studies.

All I have in mind is that after I'll check all the table rows and look for same patient ID, if it have, merge or hide that table rows and add "+". And every time the Doctor/ client click the "+" then it will expand.

But I don't know how.

```
 Patient ID       Patient Name     Study
    1111            Angela          XRAY   "+"
    2222            Bena            Ultrasound
    3333            Luis            CT Scan
```

If the "+" is clicked:

```
 Patient ID       Patient Name     Study
    1111            Angela          XRAY  
    1111            Angela          Ultrasound
    2222            Bena            Ultrasound
    3333            Luis            CT Scan
```

So far, this was my code, just trying to alert, but this would alert all the "same".

```
 $(".pid").each(function(n){
            var text = $(this).text();
            $(".pid").each(function(n){             
                var text2 = $(this).text();
                if(text == text2)
                {
                    alert(text2 + "same");
                }
            });
        });
```

Please help.

Comment: Rather than merging the `tr` elements, how about merging the data before the table is populated

Comment: Where is your markup and the code you've tried? How far were you able to get?

Comment: @Ahmed - your concluding that its better to merge them in my mysql syntax? How then could i possible show the "+" sign? I will send you the link for the image of my table.

Comment: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2v0mv03&s=8#.U7DbgpSSzlE 

here's the link for the image of my table.

Comment: I was saying if you could do it in php/asp or whatever language you are using..

Comment: Actually the process was this:

From database> all datas will be saved as text file per patient > from that folder it will be populated into the table..

The system is already existing when i come, and just add functions on it.

Comment: So all we could do now is just to manipulate the table before it will be populated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying the table is simple, it's orgainized into `rows` and `cells`. Even if it's not so (such as a CSS table), we can always use jQuery to query for the rows and cells. In fact to solve your problem we have to do 1 thing called ***grouping***. Grouping always requires us to collect all the rows into a group of the same key, the key here is the parent id. We can take benefit of the uniqueness of property in an Javascript object to save all the rows into a property of the same key. In fact sometimes a property in an object Javascript is called a key and we can get the value via it:

```
object[key] = value;
```

Here is the code detail:

**HTML**:

```
<table>
  <tr><th>Parent ID</th><th>Parent Name</th><th>Study</th></tr>
  <tr><td>1111</td><td>Angela</td><td>XRAY</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2222</td><td>Bena</td><td>Untrasound</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3333</td><td>Luis</td><td>CT Scan</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1111</td><td>Angela</td><td>Untrasound</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3333</td><td>Luis</td><td>LCD</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3333</td><td>Luis</td><td>LASER</td></tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**:

```
td {
  width:100px;
  border:1px solid black;      
}
table {
  border-collapse:collapse;    
  font-size:15px;
}
.subrow {        
  font-size:0;
  transition:font-size 400ms;
}
td > span {     
  float:right;
  width:1em;
  height:1em;       
  position:relative;
  margin-right:3px;    
}
td > span:before {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  width:80%;
  height:0;
  left:10%;
  top:50%;
  margin-top:-1px;
  border-top:2px solid black; 
  border-color:inherit; 
}
td > span.collapsed:after {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  height:80%;
  width:0;
  margin-left:-1px;
  border-left:2px solid black;
  border-color:inherit;
  left:50%;
  top:10%; 
}
td > span:hover {
  border-color:orange;
}
```

**JS**:

```
var table = $('table')[0];
var rowGroups = {};
//loop through the rows excluding the first row (the header row)
while(table.rows.length > 1){
  var row = table.rows[1];
  var id = $(row.cells[0]).text();
  if(!rowGroups[id]) rowGroups[id] = [];
  if(rowGroups[id].length > 0){
    row.className = 'subrow';
    $(row).slideUp();
  }
  rowGroups[id].push(row);
  table.deleteRow(1);
}
//loop through the row groups to build the new table content
for(var id in rowGroups){
  var group = rowGroups[id];
  for(var j = 0; j < group.length; j++){
    var row = group[j];
    if(group.length > 1 && j == 0) {
        //add + button
        var lastCell = row.cells[row.cells.length - 1];           
        $("<span class='collapsed'>").appendTo(lastCell).click(plusClick);                                         
    }
    table.tBodies[0].appendChild(row);        
  }
}
//function handling button click
function plusClick(e){
  var collapsed = $(this).hasClass('collapsed');
  var fontSize = collapsed ? 14 : 0;
  $(this).closest('tr').nextUntil(':not(.subrow)').slideToggle(400)
         .css('font-size', fontSize);
  $(this).toggleClass('collapsed');        
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FNvsQ/1/).

Comment: Thanks. Perfect :) But not yet tried, try it later and give you feedback. Thanks you so much :=))